# passing data from my page to iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to use Payment Gateway in PhoneGap but Payment Gateway not made for PhoneGap then I thought that using java script pass data to another jsp page using Iframe that control Payment Gateway .i just only pass value to that page .have anyone solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Please include what you tried, what you expect and try to reword your question to be a little more sturctured and comprehensive

Comment: PhoneGap is an open source framework for quickly building cross-platform mobile apps using HTML5, Javascript and CSS.
Its not a programming language, So there wont be any payment gateway made of PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsp file is on the server right?

You have the follow options:

1 - After you have all parameters, pass on url (?id=xxxx), and use the .jsp to get information. 

* This option is not secure

2 - On your app, put all parameters into Local Storage, and on the iFrame you can access this, using jQuery and post using AJAX

3 - Design your .jsp file to work like a web service. And do the communication using AJAX (POST/GET)

Comment: thanks ,yes jsp page on server but how to take response from server on my PhoneGap application?

Comment: POST the parameters with its value to the jsp via ajax POST, and make the server side script to authenticate the same and respond to the POST with a JSON, you can easily handle the JSON response inside your cordova/phonegap application.